# line-height works incorrectly on different browsers

Tags: html, css, text, input, vertical-alignment

I've created a `<div>` with `height:22px;` and `line-height:22px;` to center vertically the text.
And also an `<input>` with `height:22px;` (the text in the input is automatically aligned).

I noticed that the vertical alignment is incorrect with some browser, in particular on mobile.

There is an alternative property to center vertically the text, other than line-height?

And how to center the text correctly in an input-box?

```css
.myinput{
  width: 50px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: right;
}
.mydiv{
  width: 50px;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="myinput" value="EXAMPLE"/>
<div style="height:10px;"></div>
<div class="mydiv">EXAMPLE</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried css flexbox? It is a great way to control the layout and placement of children within a parent div. You can learn more about it here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Below `.mydiv` and `.myinput` will perfectly center the text horizontally and vertically inside.

```css
.myinput{
  width: 50px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.mydiv{
  width: 50px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="myinput" value="EXAMPLE"/>
<div style="height:10px;"></div>
<div class="mydiv">EXAMPLE</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do it - Maybe update the question with which browsers you're seeing problems with and we can best fit an answer.

Something like this is pretty easy and should work in most browsers..

```css
.wrapper {
height:22px;
background:#fff;
width: 100px;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid #000;
}

.wrapper:before {
content:"";
height:100%;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: middle
}

.middle {
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="middle">Here we go</div>
</div>
```